# html change td text color based on another td value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have more than 100 rows in table, so its for all rows.
the codes mentioned here working perfectly as its written.
But, need to make some changes, Currently class tg-5ma color is being changed based on value > 400.
And I need to make it work with comparison with another td ".tg-close"
if value of ".tg-5ma" > ".tg-close" then color blue and if < then color red.
now I have no idea where and how to describe another class below. pls help....

```js
$(function() {
  $(".tg-5ma").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() > 400) {
      $(this).css('color', 'blue')
    } else {
      $(this).css('color', 'red');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <style>
    td {
      border: solid black 1px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <th> Close</th>
    <th> 5ma</th>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-close">250</td>
      <td class="tg-5ma">150</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-close">550</td>
      <td class="tg-5ma">850</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-close">450</td>
      <td class="tg-5ma">50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-close">1112</td>
      <td class="tg-5ma">1500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-close">250</td>
      <td class="tg-5ma">150</td>
    </tr>
  </table>





</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Post your HTML as well.

Comment: posted HTML too.

Comment: pls check now , just corrected HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you need?

```
    if (parseInt($(this).text()) > parseInt($(this).prevAll(".tg-close").text())) {
```

Also read comment to this anwser.

https://api.jquery.com/prevAll/

You should learn [tree traversal](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/)

```js
$(function() {
  $(".tg-5ma").each(function() {
    if (parseInt($(this).text()) > parseInt($(this).prevAll(".tg-close").text())) {
      $(this).css('color', 'blue')
    } else {
      $(this).css('color', 'red');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <style>
    td {
      border: solid black 1px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <th> Close</th>
    <th> 5ma</th>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-close">250</td>
      <td class="">xx</td>
      <td class="">xxx</td>
      <td class="tg-5ma">150</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-close">550</td>
      <td class="">xx</td>
      <td class="">xxx</td>
      <td class="tg-5ma">850</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-close">450</td>
      <td class="">xx</td>
      <td class="">xxx</td>
      <td class="tg-5ma">50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-close">1112</td>
      <td class="">xx</td>
      <td class="">xxx</td>
      <td class="tg-5ma">1500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-close">250</td>
      <td class="">xx</td>
      <td class="">xxx</td>
      <td class="tg-5ma">150</td>
    </tr>
  </table>





</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 50 is < 450, still it's blue. Don't forget to cast values to number before comparison

Comment: worked fine but problem occurred when I implemented it into my project,
there are 10 colums between these 2.
so .prev(".tg-close") not working

Comment: @Avi Then use prevAll, and for next time you understand now why is important to add exact [mre]. Answers varies.

Comment: @Avi Np, please consider accepting any anwser to mark question as solved for others.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, here is a solution without jQuery:

```js
a=[...document.querySelector("tbody").children].forEach(r=>{
 let [a,b]=[...r.children].map(c=>+c.textContent)
 r.children[1].style.color=a>b?"red":"blue";
});
```

```css
td { border: solid black 1px; }
```

```html
  <table>
    <thead><tr><th> Close</th><th>5ma</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody><tr>
      <td class="tg-close">250</td>
      <td class="tg-5ma">150</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-close">550</td>
      <td class="tg-5ma">850</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-close">450</td>
      <td class="tg-5ma">50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-close">1112</td>
      <td class="tg-5ma">1500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-close">250</td>
      <td class="tg-5ma">150</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

My solution disregards any classes and instead relies on the *column order*: I compare the first two child elements of any `<tr>` found within the first `tbody`.